# CoreData: Updating the NSManagedObject from NSManagedObject Context doesn't reflect in another ManagedObjectcontext when refreshed

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I have two `NSManagedObjectContext` in two different process. One of the process is used to write the data while the other is used to read the data.

Whenever any record is updated from one `managedObjectcontext`, it is successfully saving the data. I Used Liya App to confirm if its actually getting updated.

But when I try to read the data from other process , I am still not able to read the updated value.

I tried setting setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects to YES on `NSFetchRequest` to avail nothing.

I also tried refreshObject:(NSManagedObject *)object mergeChanges:(BOOL)flag on NSManagedObjectContext.

Also , I found that , whenever a record in a Entity is updated(Written by one process) , and when I tried to fetch the updated record in other process , I could see that attribute values are updated immediately but if there is any relation in that entity , it is not updated.
Any help ?

Comment: This is a well-proven use case, and should work.  Can you post the code you are using in the two processes to read/write the data?